# Provide custom Validator for @Size

Tags: java-ee-6, bean-validation

How could I provide a custom validator implementation for a built-in constraint like @Size? in a JavaEE6 JSF Web Application

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Implement a `ConstraintValidator<MyType, Size>`, register it via an XML based constraint mapping:

```
<constraint-mappings
    xmlns="http://jboss.org/xml/ns/javax/validation/mapping" version="1.1">

    <constraint-definition annotation="javax.validation.constraints.Size">
        <validated-by include-existing-validators="false">
            <value>org.mycompany.MySizeValidator</value>
        </validated-by>
    </constraint-definition>
</constraint-mappings>
```

and add this mapping to `META-INF/validation.xml`:

```
<validation-config
    xmlns="http://jboss.org/xml/ns/javax/validation/configuration" version="1.1">

    <constraint-mapping>path/to/mapping.xml</constraint-mapping>
</validation-config>
```

You can learn more in the Hibernate Validator [reference guide](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/validator/reference/en-US/html_single/#section-mapping-xml-constraints).

Comment: It works, kudos for You. But not perfectly, because in WildFly 8.1.0 in server logs I'm seeing many lines `META-INF/validation.xml found. Parsing XML based configuration.` Why parsing this file so many times?